# Xamarin Forms Changing background color of each ViewCell in ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-color

I have reservation times in a listView like 8:00, 9:00 etc. Through JSON I retrieve reservations from remote DB that are already made. So I want to change the background color of each Cell (label) to red that are reserved and rest to green ( free appointments).

This is my xaml code:

```
    <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" />

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

ListView is populated from a model like:

```
new Termin { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "12:00", Description="" },
```

So how can I change the color of those cells?

Pseudo code of what I want:

```
for(int i=0; i< number of items in the listview; i++) {
if(reservations.contains(listview.itemAt(i)) {
//change background color of viewcell (label?) at position i
}
}
```

Comment: It is easier if you change your Model to have a Property IsReserved. After tht, in Listview viewcell just have a converter to change the color, for example.

Comment: I am way too newbie to understand half the things u said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As Bruno commented)

#### Add an `IsReserved` boolean property to your model:

```
public class Termin
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsReserved { get; set; }
}
```

#### `IValueConverter` that returns `Red` if `IsReserved` is true:

```
public class IsReservedToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value ? Color.Red : Color.Transparent);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

#### Add the namespace of your IValueConverter:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SameNameSpace;assembly=SomeAssemblyName"
```

#### Add the IValueConverter to your ContentPage.Resources

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IsReservedToColorConverter x:Key="IsReservedToColor"></local:IsReservedToColorConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

#### Consume the converter in your binding

```
<Frame BackgroundColor = "{Binding IsReserved, Converter={StaticResource IsReservedToColor}}">
```

#### Final XAML Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Forms_31_1.ListPage"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Forms_31_1;assembly=Forms_31_1" >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:IsReservedToColorConverter x:Key="IsReservedToColor"></local:IsReservedToColorConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Red">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame BackgroundColor = "{Binding IsReserved, Converter={StaticResource IsReservedToColor}}">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

#### Output:

[image]

```
posts.Add(new Termin { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "11:00" });
posts.Add(new Termin { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "12:00", IsReserved = true });
posts.Add(new Termin { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "13:00" });
posts.Add(new Termin { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "14:00" });
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, your code obviously worked.

Comment: Is there any way to instead of assigning the color with the IvalueConverter just to pass it as a parameter? for example = IsReserved=true,color red;.To be able to pass different colors to the frame?

Comment: @Pxaml Sure, you can assign the property the actual color (Color.Red, etc..) or use binding parameters and pass the color : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#binding-converter-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom view cell. I've written a custom view cell in my project and used XFGloss(XFGloss is an add-on for Xamarin.Forms projects that adds new properties to the standard XF page and control classes) to make the listView's rows colorful. Your listView will not lose the haptic feedback with XFGloss. The custom viewCell which I used is :

```
 public class MyViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        private Color BackgroundColor
        {
            get => CellGloss.GetBackgroundColor(this);
            set => CellGloss.SetBackgroundColor(this, value);
        }

        public Color EvenColor { get; set; }
        public Color UnevenColor { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (!(Parent is ListView listView))
                throw new Exception(
                    $"The Binding Context is not {typeof(ListView)}. This component works only with {typeof(ListView)}.");

            int index;
            if (listView.IsGroupingEnabled)
            {
                index = listView.TemplatedItems.GetGroupAndIndexOfItem(BindingContext).Item2;
            }
            else
            {
                index = listView.TemplatedItems.IndexOf(this);
            }

            if (index != -1)
                BackgroundColor = index % 2 == 0 ? EvenColor : UnevenColor;
        }
    }
```

and its usage in the xaml file is simple as below line :

```
<components:MyViewCell EvenColor="White" UnevenColor="#eeeeee">
```